# Angularjs ng-grid split into two columns?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I need to be able to extend the ng-grid from one column into two columns:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{ field: "name", width: 120},
                    { field: "age", width: 120 }]
    };
```

the above gives me this:

```
     __________
    | name| age|
    |----------|
    | john| 25 |
    | anne| 21 |
    | joe | 22 |
    | mary| 31 |
    ------------
```

Ideally, I would like to end up whit this below in the same table/grid:

```
     ________________________
    | name | age | name | age|
    |------------------------|
    | john | 25  | joe  | 22 |
    | anne | 21  | mary | 31 |
    -------------------------
```

json:

```
$scope.myData = [
          {name: "john", age: 25},
          {name: "anne", age: 21},
          {name: "joe", age: 22},
          {name: "mary", age: 31}
];
```

many thanks for help

Comment: Show us some lines of your myData/json. Looks like you are not using key/value pairs.

Comment: I edited post with json/data

Comment: This is strange. I would say your code is correct. Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1XCUHToRtfc5AhdfZyO1?p=preview Where do the asterisks come from?

Comment: Yes, that's cool. But how do you make 4 columns instead of 2 in the same grid?

Comment: What should be in the additional 2 columns?

Comment: The rest of the data. Basically if data has 10 values in the json I would like to split it into half, therefore I would end up with 5 values on left hands side and the rest 5 values on the right hand side. Just like my example above

Comment: Uhh, I don't think that can be done so easily. That's not a feature of ng-grid. You could prepare the array in a way that the data is sorted in a new structure of fields that could fake a multi-column layout for ng-grid. But you would loose all the fancy features like sorting, filtering etc. And it would be quiet some work. In this case I would say you better look at @vittores answer and find a way that your table looks like a ng-grid (by using the CSS) without the functionality. Sorry:-/

Comment: No problem, I thought that might be the case :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achive this would be to forget about ng-grid and implement it with plain ng-repeat and styling your layout properly.

check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/yojmjxv1/

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl as c' class='container'>
    <div ng-repeat-start='u in c.users' class='field'>
        {{ u.name }}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end class='field'>
        {{ u.age }}
    </div>    
<div>
```

and minimal styles:

```
.field { width : 120px; float:left; margin:0; }

.container { width : 480px; padding:0; }
```

Comment: I know, that would be the easiest way, but since my whole page is populated with lost of ng-grid tables, I'd like to keep it consistent.